# copy subfolders to a directory using ant

Tags: java, ant, copy

I want to copy a lot of subfolders and its content from various other folders to one specific folder.
I also want to use a patternset to choose the subfolders to copy.
For example there may be a folder wich contains a lots of subfolders which then could contain again subfolders. Now I want a patternset to get all folders named `org` or `com` or whatever and copy them where I like.
I tried it this way:

```
<target name="copysrc">
  <patternset id="set">
    <include name="**/org/**"/>
    <include name="**/com/**"/>
    <include name="**/de/**"/>
    <include name="**/net/**"/>
  </patternset>
  <copy todir="${tmp.dir2}">
    <fileset dir="${tmp.dir}" casesensitive="no">
      <patternset refid="set" />
    </fileset>
  </copy>
</target>
```

Almost did the trick but I still have all the folders above the `org`, `com`,... copied with them and not just `org`, `com`,.. and the contend below these folders.

Thanks in advance, mojoo.de

Comment: Is there supposed to be code after "I tried it this way" ??? Check your Markdown.

Comment: yes i dont know why it doesnt shows up...
maybe becouse its in <> ..

Comment: @mojoo-de, I fixed your post. You need to indent code with four spaces to be displayed properly (especially code that gets interpreted by a browser). See: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @mojoo-de, please stop editing your post. You make the XML disappear every time!

Comment: thank you, good to know i need 4 spaces to mark it as code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay got it working now .. had to use the ant contrib package code looks like

```
<target name="copysrc">
<patternset id="zuKopieren">
<include name="org/**"/>
<include name="com/**"/>
<include name="de/**"/>
<include name="net/**"/>
</patternset>
<for param="verzeichnisName">
<dirset dir="${tmp.dir}"></dirset>
<sequential> 
<copy todir="${tmp.dir2}/src">
<fileset dir="@{verzeichnisName}" casesensitive="no"><patternset refid="zuKopieren" />
</fileset>
</copy>
</sequential>
</for>
</target>
```